# The type specified in the TypeName property of ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not be found

Tags: c#, objectdatasource

Im using `VS2008` with `.Net Framework 3.5`, i have created a site from <kbd>File</kbd>-><kbd>New</kbd>-><kbd>Web Site</kbd>, I added a Master Page and Default content page. I added objects `DetailsView` and `ObjectDataSource`. To populate data in App_Code Folder i create three classes,
db (to connect to db and populate table, dataset and datareader etc.)
Screen (Model class)
ScreenDALC (Data Access Layer class)
Please note that all code behind files are not in any specific namespace

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
<Fields>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ScreenID" HeaderText="ScreenID" 
    SortExpression="ScreenID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
    ShowInsertButton="True" />
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
DataObjectTypeName="Screen" DeleteMethod="Delete" 
InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
SelectMethod="GetScreen" TypeName="ScreenDALC" UpdateMethod="Update">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

When i run application it runs with no error and i can see data on form. but when i open page with url like `http://localhost/irfu/irfulabs/newcpanel/default.aspx` i get the error message as in subject.

Please also note that what i have already tried, i put whole project in a namespace and got the same error message, i put all files in one folder but still got same error message. I have also added System.ComponentModel; to add signatures to all methods.

Comment: Do your code have a `ScreenDALC` class that is accessible by the `ObjectDataSource1`?

Comment: yes i have ScreenDALC class in App_Code folder, but i dont know how to verify if its accessible by OjectctDataSource, class can be accessed in code behind file of page, and also it works fine if i run the project, but it gives error while open through url

Comment: Most probably you had to specify the type using its full name, including the namespace. This would be something like `The.Namespace.ScreenDALC`. Also make sure the type is public.

Answer (score 0):

As there was no issue with code, after setting application folder and virtual directory on my web hosting error removed, and page open successfully.